# Tensorflow module not found in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda3

I installed tensorflow using Ananconda3 command prompt (by creating environment named tensorenviron).

But when i try to import tensorflow module in Python script using IntelliJ, it shows no such module. Please help.

IntelliJ shows me the following:
[image]

In the above picture, I can select one of the SDKs. If i select Python 3.9 (tensorenviron - I installed it using anaconda3), I can only use tensorflow module and not pandas (installed separately through pip) and other modules. I can use pandas by selecting Python 3.10 SDK but then I lose tensorflow.

[image]

Python 3.10 path is shown in the above image

[image]

Python 3.9 (having tensorflow, installed through anaconda3) path is in above figure.

I have installed latest pip, but i didn't install tensorflow using pip.

Please help me install all under same path, but tensorflow doesn't seem to support Python 3.10

Comment: Did you install the module within tenserenviron? Else you just have a named env.

Comment: Yes, I installed it within tensorenviron.

Comment: My pandas and tensorflow are installed separately and can't add both environments at the same time! Tensorflow (python 3.9) i installed using conda3 and pandas and other modules in python 3.10 through pip. How to uninstall and reinstall tensorflow in same path?

Comment: I installed the needed modules - pandas, numpy, tensorflow in the tensorenviron of anaconda3. Only desired module left is matplotlib but when i try to install matplotlib in tensorenviron, it says: Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages. Please help.

Comment: Hi! Could you try again with Python 3.8/3.9 with a fresh environment with only one Python version in your environment variable. Thanks!

Comment: I installed anaconda and used Python 3.7 to create new environment and all the modules work. Guess this version is stable...